I can't set cookies on iOS
1
With a web server build with Node.js and Express.js I'm attaching the cookies at the response.
 res.cookie('access_token', token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite:'none',
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60
    });

When a user uses chrome or mozilla everything works at expected, but on safari getting an auth error because can't handle cross-over cookies, any solution?
I have my backend and frontend separately!
app.use(
   cors({
      origin: BASE_URL_FRONTEND,
      credentials: true
   })
);

solve express cookie problem
